# how to call a class method in python

Tags: python

I have the following class:

```
class SoftwarePackage:
    def __init__(self, name, description, order_of_installation, url):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.order_of_installation = order_of_installation
        self.url = "http://localhost:9090/api/software_package"

        def create():
            post_data = {"name": self.name, "description": self.description,
                         "order_of_installation": self.order_of_installation}
            post_data = json.dumps(post_data)
            req = urllib2.Request(url, post_data)

            req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            return urllib2.urlopen(req, post_data)
```

When I try to call the "create" method like this:

```
sp = SoftwarePackage(name="my-package-1", description="my-package-1-desc", order_of_installation=0, url="")
sp.create()
```

I get this error:

```
   sp.create()
AttributeError: SoftwarePackage instance has no attribute 'create'
```

What is the proper way to call this class method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made `create` a *nested function*; you indented it to far and it is part of the `__init__` method. It is currently a local variable in that method and not usable.

*Unindent* the whole function to be level with `def __init__(...):`, and add a `self` argument:

```
class SoftwarePackage:
    def __init__(self, name, description, order_of_installation, url):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.order_of_installation = order_of_installation
        self.url = "http://localhost:9090/api/software_package"

    def create(self):
        post_data = {"name": self.name, "description": self.description,
                     "order_of_installation": self.order_of_installation}
        post_data = json.dumps(post_data)
        req = urllib2.Request(self.url, post_data)

        req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        return urllib2.urlopen(req, post_data)
```

The `url` local name is probably meant to be the `url` attribute on the instance, so I replaced that with `self.url`.

Comment: The `url` member data needs to be referenced using `self`